# How to change SMS class to 0?

Tags: android, sms

Is there any possible way in Android OS or external library to send SMS with class 0 (send ***flash SMS***), which is immediately displayed on recipient phone ?

I know that SMS class is saved in SMS Message Headers, maybe I should change them ?